# How to dim background when using the BottomSheet from the support library?

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, androiddesignsupport, bottom-sheet

How can the background be dimmed just like it is shown [here](https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_8/material_ext_publish/0Bzhp5Z4wHba3UzA3RDctV2k0YUk/components_bottomsheets_modal2.png)?

I've set it up normally using the `CoordinatorLayout` and the `BottomSheetBehavior`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will simply show a bottom sheet.

```
public class MyBottomSheet extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {
    private static final String TAG = "MyBottomSheet";

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final BottomSheetDialog dialog = (BottomSheetDialog) super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);

        final View view = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.my_custom_view, null);

        dialog.setContentView(view);
        behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from((View) view.getParent());

        return dialog;
    }

    public void show(final FragmentActivity fragmentActivity) {
        show(fragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager(), TAG);
    }
}
```

To close the dialog simply as normal call `close()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    bottomSheetBehavior.addBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {}

                @Override
                public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {

                            (your_layout/view).setAlpha(1 - slideOffset);

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

use `BottomSheetDialog`

basically it's a dialog (i.e support dim) and support modal bottom sheets behaviour give it a try

Comment: Does not cut it. Need a `BottomSheetDialogFragment` since the normal Dialog can't be fullscreen.