# Why am I able to click "behind" the bottomsheet in Android?

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I have a `BottomSheet` in my Activity.

I'm calling `behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);` to show the bottom sheet and it works fine, but the problem I have is that I can somehow click on the empty space of my bottom sheet to trigger `onClick` event of a view that is behind the bottom sheet.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: What version of the Support Library are you using? Have you upgraded to the latest (24.2.1 as of now)?

Comment: yes, I'm using 24.2.1.

Comment: I found an exact same question that was asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37596701/dim-screen-and-block-interaction-with-bottomsheets but doesnt seem to have an answer yet

Comment: have you found answer yet?

Comment: @Andrea no. i didnt find any

Comment: this is still an issue with the latest support libraries

Comment: did you get any solution?

Comment: the project I'm working on has switched to AndroidX and I couldn't reproduce clicking through the Bottom Sheet

Answer (score 69, accepted):

A simple solution is to add the

> android:clickable="true"

attribute to the layout that you are using for your bottom sheet.  That way it will capture all clicks, and not let them bleed through. You do not have to set an `onClick` method for it, as you have no need to handle them.

Comment: i've tried to set clickable=true to the parent view but no luck :(

Comment: Please post the layout.

Comment: if `android:clickable="false"` doesn't work, try to `setEnable(false)` on the clickable controls below the buttonsheet when the bottom sheet is expanded. Use `slideOffset`to get the slide direction

Comment: You can also set `bottomSheet.setClickable(false);`in Your code

Comment: The answer works out fine, but I didn't understand the logic. Could you please help me understand?

Comment: @NishchayZacariah If a view is not clickable, it will allow the touch to go to the view under it. For example, you may have an imageView in a button, but since it is not clickable, it allows the click to go through to the button below it.

Answer (score 4):

I faced same issue !

Add `android:clickable=true` to your BottomSheet ! Should look like below !

```
<LinearLayout
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/materialWhite"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">
</LinearLayout>
```