# BottomSheet click fires through

Tags: android, kotlin, bottom-sheet

I have a BottomSheet with some non-clickable content. This BottomSheet is sliding over a RecyclerView.

Problem is when I tap on the BottomSheet, the RecyclerView item behind it fires (which of course shouldn't happen). The list also scrolls when scrolling on the BottomSheet.

I've tried to set `android:clickable=false` on the container of the BottomSheet with no effect.

Is there an obvious trick for preventing that?

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/39738467/6016830

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `android:clickable=true` on the container of the `BottomSheet` instead of `android:clickable=false`.

Comment: Thanks man, I don't know why my logic told me to try with `false` (which actually is the default). The `android:clickable=true` did the trick. thanks.

Comment: Sorry man, can't accept you answer before the 10 minute time gap :-)

Comment: Please up-vote this answer, If helped. Happy Coding!