# Can't drag BottomSheet when clickable="true"? If not set clickable then click goes through it and fire on Recycleview item under it

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, bottom-sheet, android-bottomnavigationview

Here is my Persistent BottomSheet

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/bs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bottom_sheet_background"
    android:elevation="2dp"

    android:padding="@dimen/base_margin"
    app:behavior_hideable="true"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="@dimen/bottom_sheet_peek_height"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">
```

When User scrolls RecycleView, BottomNavigation hides and I reduce height of BottomSheet accordingly in RecycleView's addOnScrollListener using:

```
binding.rv.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    //148 = 80(bottom navigation) + 56(bottom sheet)
    if (dy < 0)//scroll down
        bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(136, true);
    else if (dy > 0)//scroll up
        bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(56, true);
}
```

After BottomNavigation is hidden and BottomSheet height is reduced, if BottomSheet is clickable,

(either through code `binding.bs.bs.setClickable(false);` or through xml `android:clickable="true"`)

I can't drag it to expand. If it is not clickable, click event goes through it and user click on RecycleView item underneath it.

Even when its height is not reduced and it isn't clickable then also click event goes under it and fire on RecycleView item.

I also tried setting nestedScrolling, which allowed expanding but after that start creating issues when collapsing. :(

UPDATE:
I noticed BottomSheet drag not works when I set Bottomsheet clickable and its peekheight < 80 dp, ie the height of BottomNavigation.

Reference:

[Why am I able to click "behind" the bottomsheet in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39734951/why-am-i-able-to-click-behind-the-bottomsheet-in-android)

Comment: try adding android:translationZ="2dp"  instead of clickable true

Comment: Tried. It has no effect. When user click, click fire on underneath recycleview.
Also tried it after removing elevation ="2dp".

Answer (score 0):

I had same use case of having a recycler view inside a bottom sheet and here's what my Bottom sheet XML looks like. Please try to check if this works for you!

Apart from this, I did not actually get it why you want to reduce the height of the bottom sheet, as Bottom sheet has the behavior  of self adjusting its height respect to the content inside it.

Please if possible share your use case so that it will be easier for the community to answer which gonna hit the bonsai. Thanks!

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        layout="@layout/item_progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rootView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_sheet_rounded_background"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/background_gray"
        android:clipToPadding="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/title_rl"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingVertical="16dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                android:height="24sp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/silka_bold"
                android:text="@string/error_select_prescription"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color_semi_black"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_close"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_close_btn_gray" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/btn_gray"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title_rl" />

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerViewPrescription"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/dimen_16dp"
                tools:itemCount="10" />
        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

        <include
            android:id="@+id/btn_select_and_proceed"
            layout="@layout/sticky_footer_design_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I have bottom navigation as well as bottom sheet in my app. When user scrolls, bottom navigation hides. But if bottom sheet not reduce its height then user see inner content of bottom sheet. So I am synching movement of bottom sheet and bottom navigation.
Bottom Sheet showing currently playing song so I can't hide it fully. It can only be collapsed.

Answer (score 0):

```
val bottomSheet = dialog!!.findViewById<View>(R.id.design_bottom_sheet) as FrameLayout
val behavior: BottomSheetBehavior<*> = BottomSheetBehavior.from<View>(bottomSheet)
behavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
```

[image]

These all are the states which you can use to manipulate the height or basically the behavior of the BottomSheet.