# Restrict user interaction with rest of the UI while bottom sheet is open

Tags: flutter, bottom-sheet

I have to avoid user interaction with rest of the UI (above the bottom sheet) while the bottom sheet is open.

```
_scaffoldKey.currentState.showBottomSheet((context) {

    return sheetWidget();

});
```

Similar to something like [Dim Screen and Block Interaction with BottomSheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37596701/dim-screen-and-block-interaction-with-bottomsheets) this. Didn't get any idea to achieve this in `Flutter`.

Would like to hear some tips, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try showModalBottomSheet()
It brings up a BottomSheetModal while the Rest of the UI is Dim and if you click out of the Modal then Modal will go back.

Visit https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html to view usage

Answer (score 1):

You can use [showModalBottomSheet](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html). It is "a modal bottom sheet is an alternative to a menu or a dialog and prevents the user from interacting with the rest of the app."

Your code will now be:

```
 showModalBottomSheet<void>(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return sheetWidget();
 });
```